# ios Storyboard - Push a title onto the View Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

Is this piece of code suppose to set the title on the ViewController I am connecting to?

The 2 UIViewControllers are connected via a push segue - the first one is embedded in a NavigationController.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
 if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"settingsSegue"])
 {

     self.navigationItem.title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Custom Title"];

 }
 }
```

It does not work for me, but the syntax is right.

Advance Thanks:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the title in the `viewDidLoad` of the destination viewcontroller using a property in the destination VC:

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"settingsSegue"]) {
    MyDestinationViewController *mdvc = segue.destinationViewController;
    mdvc.myTitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Custom Title"];
}
```

Then in the `viewDidLoad` event in MyDestinationViewController.h:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *myTitle;
```

In MyDestinationViewController.m:

```
@synthesize myTitle;
```

And finally in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.title = myTitle;
```

Comment: Sorry looked promising:-) and again no errors, but it is not coming through sorry

Comment: I got it working - had a blond moment and forgot to link a ViewController to the header file in Storyboard:-)

Answer (score 2):

The above answer works for me with one exception...

Change

```
self.title = myTitle;
```

to

```
self.navigationItem.title = myTitle;
```

Comment: Well Somehow the myTitle value is not pushed across - I checked with NSLog which returns (null)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the title directly in the segue as well, there is no need to go through a property:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"settingsSegue"]) {    
        segue.destinationViewController.navigationItem.title = @"Custom Title";
    }
}
```

Or, what I needed, to set the title of the pushed view controller to the title of the table cell that was clicked:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"settingsSegue"]) {   
        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIndexPath];        
        segue.destinationViewController.navigationItem.title = cell.textLabel.text;
    }
}
```